Issue while installing a Starter Template in Wordpress
I'm trying to create a wordpress website using localhost, but I'm having problem when I'm installing a template from Astra Starter Template in wordpress.
This is the error that I'm getting when I'm trying to install it:

I already configured the max upload file size in php.ini to 512M. Any guess on what's the problem here?

It looks like the issue is with the file you are trying to import. Could you please check if that file has valid content.
